# Thank you for offering me ["an" or "the" or "this"] opportunity to interview for the Sales and Marketing Assistant position? What is the difference?

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

Thank you for offering me **["an" or "the" or "this"]** opportunity to interview for the Sales and Marketing Assistant position?

What is the difference?

Or, are they interchangeable in this case?

I got so confused.....and spent the whole night thinking about it....thanks a lot!

Comment: They are all good. You might want to change "interview" to "be interviewed", however.

Comment: is it a matter of perspective? 
"From their perspective they are probably interviewing multiple people and so gave you **an** opportunity. From your perspective you only have one chance to impress them so it is **the** opportunity. "

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AN** is an indefinite article. You use indefinite articles when describing something "not specific".

> I need **an** apple. *Not a specific apple, but any apple.

Use AN when talking about a thing which is new, unknown, or introduced to a listener for the first time. Also use AN when you are asking about the existence of something.

> Jennifer is **an** optometrist. *Jennifer is being introduced*

AN can also be used to introduce what TYPE of thing we are talking about.

> This is **an** excellent movie. *Describing the movie*

It is important to know that AN can only be used with singular nouns.

**THE** and **THIS** are definite articles. They are used to describe something "specific". Use THE/THIS when talking about something which is already known to the listener or which has been previously mentioned, introduced, or discussed.

> There is a pencil in my purse. **The** pencil is yellow.
>
> Thank you for walking **the** dog.

Unlike AN, THE can be used with both singular and plural nouns. Like AN, THIS can only be used with singular nouns.

While they all 3 do technically work, I would suggest using THE or THIS as it specifically refers to the interview opportunity. If you were asking for an interview, AN would be more appropriate, in my opinion.

> Can you get me **an** interview with your manager?